# Topaz Workbench error message: 92003: An error occurred while writing data to the channel

Tags: ide, topaz-workbench

While Topaz Workbench is starting the error message "92003: An error occurred while writing data to the channel" shows up. That is making one of my configured repository to not be listed there. How to resolve it?

Message:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What resolved my case, as a workaround, was to verify the amount of fa_commgr.exe processes in the Task Manager (I am using Windows 10), kill all of them, and then start Topaz again, this way it started normally (without that error message), and my repository was listed again.

Task Manager and fa_commgr.exe process instance (there were 4 instances I don't know why... yet):

[image]

My repository was listed again:

[image]